# In excel is there a way to quickly rewrite add new text to different formulas in different cells via a macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple cells with different formulas in them, but they are returning the value 0 instead of blank

I would like to rewrite all of the formulas to instead read (if currently cells read `=formula`)

```
=if(formula="","",formula)
```

Can I write a macro to do this for all highlighted cells, maybe using the replace function?

I'm trying to understand how to use this macro language to add text before and after

```
Replace(c.Formula, ")", ",A7)")
```

Comment: You can use `replace` with field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Replace Formulas

- I think it is needless to say that you need to write better formulas.
- The following is a tool that lets you select a range that it will search for formulas. Each formula that it encounters, will be changed to the following:

  ```
  =IF(formula=0,"",formula)
  ```

**The Code**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub AddIfBlank()
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Convert To If-Blank Formula"
    Const AI_PROMPT As String = "Select a range"

    If Selection Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Not TypeOf Selection Is Range Then Exit Sub
    Dim aiDefault As String: aiDefault = Selection.Address
    
    Dim srg As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Set srg = Application.InputBox( _
            AI_PROMPT, PROC_TITLE, aiDefault, , , , , 8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If srg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Canceled.", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim drg As Range, cel As Range
    
    For Each cel In srg.Cells
        If cel.HasFormula Then
            If drg Is Nothing Then Set drg = cel Else Set drg = Union(drg, cel)
        End If
    Next cel
    
    If drg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No formulas found.", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim arg As Range, Data(), r As Long, c As Long, cCount As Long
    Dim Rep As String
    
    For Each arg In drg.Areas
        If arg.Cells.CountLarge = 1 Then
            ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = arg.Formula
        Else
            Data = arg.Formula
        End If
        cCount = UBound(Data, 2)
        For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
            For c = 1 To cCount
                Rep = Right(Data(r, c), Len(Data(r, c)) - 1)
                Data(r, c) = "=IF(" & Rep & "=0,""""," & Rep & ")"
            Next c
        Next r
        arg.Formula = Data
    Next arg
                
    MsgBox "Formulas updated.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that works perfectly. It was some inherited formulas someone else had written that I need to fix and this will save me so much time.